# Is it possible to move a user to a voice channel in a different guild? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am working on a multi guild project and have been trying to move users between multiple guilds. The user is a member of both guilds, and so is the bot. When I attempt to move the user, I am receiving the 'User not connected to voice' error. I assume this is a limitation of the discord API - probably regarding privacy issues.
If anyone has any ideas I would love to hear them.

Comment: Discord doesn’t let bots or users switch user voices between guilds

Comment: @MrMythical I am aware - hoping for a work around here

Comment: There is probably no workaround at the time. There would be, if Discord allowed bots to join `GuildMember`s to `VoiceChannel`s. Or that users could be connected to more than one voice at a time.